# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'app-my-profile' is not a known element:

Tags: angular

I am getting this error :  Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'app-my-profile' is not a known element,  when i created my profile service

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LayoutService } from './core/services/layout.service';
import { MyprofileService } from './core/services/myprofile.service';
import { TopNavComponent } from './top-nav/top-nav.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TopNavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    TabsModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [LayoutService,MyprofileService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyprofileService {

  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: In which module have you created `app-my-profile`? Have you declared and exported it properly? If yes, make sure you import that module too.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the error is more related to a component rather than to your service.
Like having a component whose selector is 'app-my-profile'(MyProfileComponent by default).
As this component isn't included into the declarations array of your module, he's unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure its a missing component named app-my-profile, as it mentioned above.